# Can I assume (log-)normality for this sample?

Tags: interpretation, lognormal-distribution, qq-plot

Here's a Q-Q plot for my sample (notice the logarithmic Y axis); $n = 1000$:

[image]
As pointed out by whuber, this indicates that the underlying distribution is left-skewed (the right tail is shorter).

Using `shapiro.test` (on the log-transformed data) in R, I get a test statistic of $W = 0.9718$ and a p-value of $5.172\cdot10^{-13}$, which means that we formally **reject** the null hypothesis $H_0 : \text{the sample is normal distributed}$ at the 95% confidence level.

My question is: Is this good enough in practice for further analysis assuming (log-)normality? In particular, I would like to calculate confidence intervals for the means of similar samples using the approximate method by Cox and Land (described in the paper: Zou, G. Y., cindy Yan Huo and Taleban, J. (2009). Simple confidence intervals for lognormal means and their differences with environmental applications. Environmetrics 20, 172–180):

```
ci <- function (x) {
        y <- log(x)
        n <- length(y)
        s2 <- var(y)
        m <- mean(y) + s2 / 2
        z <- qnorm(1 - 0.05 / 2) # 95%
        #z <- qnorm(1 - 0.10 / 2) # 90%
        d <- z * sqrt(s2 / n + s2 * s2 / (2 * (n - 1)))

        return(c(exp(m - d), exp(m + d)))
}
```

I've noticed that the confidence intervals tend to be centered around a point which is slightly above the actual sample mean. For example:

```
> mean(x)
[1] 82.3076
> y <- log(x)
> exp(mean(y) + var(y) / 2)
[1] 91.22831
```

I think these two values should be the same under $H_0$.

Comment: The distribution definitely does not fit well in the right tail.

Comment: This Q-Q plot shows the data have a much *shorter* right tail than a lognormal distribution: it is *left* skewed compared to a lognormal. You should therefore be leery of using lognormal-based procedures.

Comment: @whuber yes, you are right about it being left skewed rather than right skewed. Should I update the question?

Comment: Sure: we appreciate improvements to questions.

Comment: NB: please note that by "left skewed" I explicitly meant that the *right* tail is short, not that the left tail is long. This is evident by how the points at the *right* of the plot fall *below* the reference line. Because the points at the left of the plot are (relatively) close to the reference line, it is incorrect to characterize this distribution as having a "longer left tail." The distinction is important here, because the right tail *ought* to have far greater influence on the estimated mean than the left tail does (whereas *both* tails influence its confidence interval).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These data have a short tail compared to a lognormal distribution, not unlike a Gamma distribution:

```
set.seed(17)
par(mfcol=c(1,1))
x <- rgamma(500, 1.9)
qqnorm(log(x), pch=20, cex=.8, asp=1)
abline(mean(log(x)) + .1,1.2*sd(log(x)), col="Gray", lwd=2)
```

[image: QQPlot]

Nevertheless, because the data *are* strongly right-skewed, we can expect the largest values to play an important role in estimating the mean and its confidence interval.  Therefore **we should anticipate that a lognormal (LN) estimator will tend to *overestimate* the mean and the two confidence limits**.

Let's check and, for comparison, use the usual estimators: that is, the sample mean and its normal-theory confidence interval.  Note that the usual estimators rely only on the approximate normality of the *sample mean*, not of the data, and--with such a large dataset--can be expected to work well.  To do this, we need a slight modification of the `ci` function:

```
ci <- function (x, alpha=.05) {
  z <- -qnorm(alpha / 2)
  y <- log(x); n <- length(y); s2 <- var(y)
  m <- mean(y) + s2 / 2
  d <- z * sqrt(s2 / n + s2 * s2 / (2 * (n - 1)))
  exp(c(mean=m, lcl=m-d, ucl=m+d))
}
```

Here is a parallel function for the normal-theory estimates:

```
ci.u <- function(x, alpha=.05) {
 mean(x) + sd(x) * c(mean=0, lcl=1, ucl=-1) / sqrt(length(x)) * qnorm(alpha/2)
}
```

Applied to this simulated dataset, the outputs are

```
> ci(x)
   mean     lcl     ucl 
2.03965 1.87712 2.21626 
> ci.u(x)
   mean     lcl     ucl 
1.94301 1.81382 2.07219
```

The normal-theory estimates produced by `ci.u` look a little closer to the true mean of $1.9$, but it's hard to tell from one dataset which procedure tends to work better. To find out, let's simulate a lot of datasets:

```
trial <- function(n=500, k=1.9) {
  x <- rgamma(n, k)
  cbind(ci(x), ci.u(x))
}
set.seed(17)
sim <- replicate(5000, trial())
```

We are interested in comparing the outputs to the true mean of $1.9$.  A panel of histograms is revealing in that regard:

```
xmin <- min(sim)
xmax <- max(sim)
h <- function(i, ...) {
  b <- seq(from=floor(xmin*10)/10, to=ceiling(xmax*10)/10, by=0.1)
  hist(sim[i,], freq=TRUE, breaks=b, col="#a0a0FF", xlab="x", xlim=c(xmin, xmax), ...)
  hist(sim[i,sim[i,] >= 1.9], add=TRUE,freq=TRUE, breaks=b, col="#FFa0a0",
                              xlab="x", xlim=c(xmin, xmax), ...)
}
par(mfcol=c(2,3))
h(1, main="LN Estimate of Mean")
h(4, main="Sample Mean")
h(2, main="LN LCL")
h(5, main="LCL")
h(3, main="LN UCL")
h(6, main="UCL")
```

[image: Histograms]

It is now clear that the lognormal procedures tend to overestimate the mean and the confidence limits, whereas the usual procedures do a good job.  We can estimate the coverages of the confidence interval procedures:

```
> sapply(c(LNLCL=2, LCL=5, LNUCL=3, UCL=6), function(i) sum(sim[i,] > 1.9)/dim(sim)[2])
 LNLCL    LCL  LNUCL    UCL 
0.2230 0.0234 1.0000 0.9648
```

This calculation says:

- The LN lower limit will fail to cover the true mean about 22.3% of the time (instead of the intended 2.5%).
- The usual lower limit will fail to cover the true mean about 2.3% of the time, close to the intended 2.5%.
- The LN upper limit will *always* exceed the true mean (instead of falling below it 2.5% of the time as intended).  This makes it a two-sided 100% - (22.3% + 0%) = 77.7% confidence interval instead of a 95% confidence interval.
- The usual upper limit will fail to cover the true mean about 100 - 96.5 = 3.5% of the time.  This is a little greater than the intended value of 2.5%.  The usual limits therefore comprise a two-sided 100% - (2.3% + 3.5%) = 94.2% confidence interval instead of a 95% confidence interval.

The reduction of the nominal coverage from 95% to 77.7% for the lognormal interval is terrible.  The reduction to 94.2% for the usual interval is not bad at all and can be attributed to the effect of the skewness (of the raw data, not of their logarithms).

We have to conclude that **further analyses *of the mean* should *not* assume lognormality.**

Be careful! Some procedures (such as prediction limits) will be more sensitive to skewness than these confidence limits for the mean, so their skewed distribution may need to be accounted for. However, it looks unlikely that lognormal procedures will perform well with these data for practically any intended analysis.

Comment: Wow, this answer blows me away. Thank you so much! How come you use `abline()` instead of `qqline()` (which produces a different line) in the first example?

Comment: Your `trial()` function does not use its arguments.

Comment: OK, so... I modified your code a bit. Not sure I can fit it in a comment (should I edit the question or make a new answer?). Anyway, this is what I did: Instead of drawing 5000 new samples from the gamma distribution, I drew 5000 samples of size 500 from my original ($n=1000$) sample and replaced 1.9 (the true mean in your samples) with the sample mean of my original sample. Whew. Well, the results? Nominal coverage for the lognormal interval: 94.8%. Nominal coverage for the usual interval: 93.6%. What do you think?

Comment: You are bootstrapping, which is a good idea, but you're not getting relevant information: you need to draw samples (with replacement) of *the same size* as your original.  I am surprised that you are getting such good coverages with the lognormal procedure: unless your data are quite different from those portrayed in the question, I think there may be an error in your code. Are you perhaps not using the resamples to estimate *all* the parameters of the distribution?

Comment: A couple of things: My smaller samples were not size 500, they were size 100. My mistake. So I tried with different sizes, and indeed the coverage changes drastically (down to 43% for size 500). I didn't realise that this could even happen. Also, the upper limit is always very close to 1, something like 0.996 for the $n=100$. The data I used were the exact same as in the question. I am passing the resamples to `ci` and `ci.u` and using the sample mean of the *original* sample (where the resample was drawn from) as the true mean. Maybe there is an error in my reasoning.

Comment: [The code I used](https://gist.github.com/d7600c292fd8dff93a4c).

Comment: Nice job! For bootstrapping, modify `trial`: `trial <- function(y) {
  x <- sample(y, length(y), TRUE);
  cbind(ci(x), ci.u(x))
}`. Then issue just *one* command, `sim <- sapply(1:5000, function(i) trial(x))`. You might wish to explore the histograms of the six rows of `sim` afterwards.

Comment: +1, I especially like the subtle point that prediction intervals will be more sensitive to the distributional shape than confidence intervals for the mean.

Comment: In the `ci` function, the bounds are calculated as follows: `m <- mean(y) + s2 / 2` ... `exp(c(mean=m, lcl=m-d, ucl=m+d))`. Could we replace the first line by `m <- log(mean(x))`? These two are supposed to be equal under $H_0$, and using the actual mean of the sample should prevent it from over-/underestimating the mean in slightly skewed distributions. I suppose this is just an ad-hoc change with no basis in statistics. Doing the bootstrap (with $n=1000$) using this method, the left and right limits fail to cover the true mean 0.16% and 0.26% of the time, respectively (99.58% conf. int.)

Comment: I do not understand what $H_0$ might be when you're computing a confidence interval. In no case will the logarithm of the mean equal the mean of the logarithm (well, except when all the data are equal to a common value).

Comment: Er, yeah, sorry, I have no idea where the $H_0$ came from. What I meant to say was that these two, `mean(log(X) + var(log(X)) / 2` and `log(mean(X))`, are equal when X is log-normal distributed.

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, that equality requires that $X$ be *very* close to lognormal, which your data aren't. There do exist variations of the usual normal-theory confidence interval to adjust for *skewness* in the distribution. One is named after "Chen" as described in Millard & Neerchal, *Environmental Statistics.*